# Why is Xcode entering an uncalled funtion breakpoint with __block?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, block

```
@interface DemoClass()
@property dispatch_queue_t queue;
@end

@implementation DemoClass

-(instancetype)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.queue = dispatch_queue_create("ccccc", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)notCallFunction
{
    dispatch_async(self.queue, ^{
        __block NSDate *noUse = nil;
        NSLog(@"notCallFunction:%@",noUse);
    });
}

-(void)doSomething
{
    __block NSError *error = nil;
    dispatch_async(self.queue, ^{
        error = nil;//when add this line,notCallFunction can enter "__block NSDate *noUse =     nil" break point
        NSLog(@"doSomething");
    });
}
```

When I set a breakpoint in `__block NSDate *noUse = nil;`
and call `doSomething`, Xcode locates the line `__block NSDate *noUse = nil`.

Comment: Unrelated - but why are you declaring `NSDate *noUse` with `__block` it's not required.

Comment: It just makes the code more simple. Actually, "NSDate *nouse" position has more complex code which needs __block.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem in the past. Turning off compiler optimizations for debug builds (`-O0`) fixed it for me.